# How to handle a native OS (Ubuntu) file upload window in selenium in java

Tags: selenium

How to handle a native OS (Ubuntu) file upload window in selenium in java.
Can Auto-It tool be used for this?
If not please let me know the tool name
Please anyone help me on this... thanks in advance

Comment: Agree on duplicate. While the language is different the required Selenium hooks are unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the file upload using java, you can use java `Robot` class.

With this class you can perform keyboard operation.

Following is code for MAC - Hopefully it works for Ubuntu.

```
public void upload(String fileLocation) throws Exception {

// Create object of Robot class
Robot robot = new Robot();
StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(fileLocation);

// Copy file path in Clipboard   
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);


            // Hit Command + Shift + G to go to particular path
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
            // Hit Command + V to paste the path from clipboard
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            // Hit Enter
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.delay(2000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```